# Проблема добавление данных laravel

Tags: php, laravel

всем доброе время суток не могу добавть запись в чем проблема именно в моей ситуации

```
    public function addtovar(Request $request){
      $item = new Tovars([
       "title"=> $request->get('title'),
        "articl"=> $request->get("art"),
        "proezvod"=> $request->get('proiz'),
        'cuntry'=> $request->get('count'),
        'obem'=> $request->get('ob'),
        'ypakovka'=> $request->get('yp'),
        'srok' => $request->get('srok'),
        'svet'=> $request->get('svet'),
        'vkys' => $request->get('vkys'),
        'aromat'=>$request->get('arom'),
        'gs' => $request->get('gs'),
        'opisan'=>$request->get('text'),
        'fact' => $request->get('ifs'),
        'sena'=> $request->get('sena'),
        'sena2'=> $request->get('sena2'),
        'kolichestvo' => $request->get('kol'),
        'sklad' => $request ->get('sklad'),
        'id_category' => $request->get('cat')

    ]);
    $item->save();
    return response()->json("ok");
}
```

}
Данные получаю от react

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? Не доходит до выполнения, или выполняется с ошибкой (какой?) или приходят не те данные? С телепатией напряженка

Comment: А вы указвли в моделе разрешенные поля для массового  заполнения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как ты получаешь данные не столь важно, важно приходят ли они до бека.
Попробуй вывести для начала, то что тебе приходит в request

```
dd($request->all());
```

и посмотри что тебе приходит, а там пиши, может что уже увидим

 Тыкая пальцем в небо могу сказать 2 распространенные ошибки 

Скорее всего у тебя ошибка в маршруте или при добавлении данных (в консоли, в разделе "network" обычно пишет по какой причине не удалось добавить.)

Comment: и да, еще совет, при создании контроллера создавай его с --resource, это сразу генерирует тебе правильные названия методов

Answer (score 1):

перед сохранением советую добавить валидацию

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'articl' => 'required|string|max:30'
        ...
    ]);
```

после чего ошибка скорее всего уйдет, если не ошиблись в названии колонок и правильно провалидируете